# Shinyapps.io not working on Google Chrome

Tags: r, google-chrome, shiny, dygraphs

I have an R Shiny app that is deployed on the shinyapps.io server. Other things are great, except that one of my dygraph() will sort of crash the session every time it is loaded.

The problem only appears on Google Chrome. The app works fine with Safari or Firefox. I've tried to troubleshoot and it seems that the problem is dygraph's compatibility with Chrome. It seems that there is a potential memory leak of dygraph, so that once the data it is trying to plot reach certain size the session will crash.

My Shinyapp instance has a 8GB memory, and my data is around 6000 rows.

The app is viewable at https://datastories.shinyapps.io/datastories/.
The problematic graph is under Visuals -> system performance.

Please help me out here if you've encountered similar situation or know the solution to it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Cant reproduce with chrome Version 53.0.2785.143 m (64-bit)

Comment: can't reproduce, same version as above (perhaps you could edit your question to list your Chrome version?)

Comment: My chrome version is Version 54.0.2840.71 (64-bit).
To reproduce, first click into visuals -> system performance, and then click any other tabs under visuals and then no graphs can be loaded. I've tried with different devices and versions of chrome so it should be reproducible.

Answer (score -1):

It is working in my google chrome and i am using Version 53.0.2785.143 (64-bit)

I suggest to uninstall, clean cache and reinstall chrome and version equal or higher than mine to check if it solves the problem.

Comment: The problem is not so obvious. But after you click visuals->system performance, it won't be able to load any other graphs under visuals.